# Task Scheduler Not able to display a user interactive pop up with Run whether user is logged on or not options

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks

I have created user interactive pop up using power shell script and schedule a task using task scheduler.

I want to run this script when user is logged off, so that I have selected the "whether user is logged on or not" option  in Task Scheduler.

But when I have selected this option then I'm not able to see the pop up which I have designed as a PowerShell script to show the information.

I want to run this task as user interactive but it should also run this script when user is logged off, and once the pop-up times out, it will trigger some action.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: How does someone interact with a pop up if they are not logged on? Also, this site helps you with your code issues, you've posted no code, so we cannot help you with it.

Comment: @Compo- That's why above mentioned, if it is log off then will do action once pop up time out, but when user will logged on then pop up should display to the user.

Comment: The best method would be to determine whether a user is logged on, and if so, run the pop up, if not, perform the other action. A scheduled task run when no-one is logged in is run under the system user context, and has no GUI.